# Why do libraries use annotations?

Tags: java, android, annotations

I always wondered why android support libraries use annotations?

I have implemented some of the common android libraries like ButterKnife, Retrofit. However, I see one common behavior in these. They use annotations to
provide their functionalities. 
I wondered why didn't they used some method or interfaces to implement the functionality they provide, is there any advantage in using annotation over these?

Comment: Because that's the way they wrote it. Unclear what sort of an answer you're looking for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I always wondered why android support libraries use annotations?
>
> I have implemented some of the common android libraries like
>   ButterKnife, Retrofit. However I see one common behavior in these.
>   They use annotations to provide their functionalities.

There are different purposes for default annotations and specific annotations that used by ButterKnife or Retrofit. Default annotations like `@Override`, `@NonNull`, `@StringRes`, `@IntRes`, etc is a way to tell the compiler about specific constraint for the code.

Specific annotations like `@BindView` or `@OnClick` in ButterKnife are used for code generation. ButterKnife Annotation processor will be looking for all the matching annotations and generating the code according to the annotation as the rule.

> I wondered why didn't they used some method or interfaces to implement
>   the functionality they provide, is there any profit in using
>   annotation over these?

They can provide the functionally like you have said but it's usually achieved by using a reflection which comes at a high cost in terms of performance and hard to maintain, more details at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101187/are-there-problems-with-using-reflection for details.  Hence code generation is used.

Answer (score 1):

Annotations are basically used for notifying compiler about some actions. like:
@Override annotation will inform compiler to check that this method is being override. Compiler will look after that the condition is being full fill or it will throw an exceptions.